# How to pass information about list items to new list activity?

Tags: java, android, ios, android-intent

Coming from iOS, I have trouble to decide what's the best ways to pass objects when changing from one activity to another. On iOS, it's easy because you instantiate the view controller which you are going to display. That means you can just set the object as a property of the view controller or you call a method on it where you pass in relevant data, this doesn't work Android as an activity is basically started by the framework itself, that's why you need to use an intent.

From this post, I understood that the most two popular approaches to this problem would be to either use Parceable or some sort of serialization mechanism (such as GSON).

I would like to know what the appropriate way to pass the data would be in my case. I have two classes:

```
public class Series{
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String imageTitle;
  private List<Episode>chapters;
}

public class Episode{
  private int episode;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String imageTitle;
}
```

I am using two list activities, the first one is a `Series` list. When the user selects a Series item in the list, another list activity will be started and show all the chapters.

How do I properly pass the information about the chapters that belong to the selected series to the new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understood that the most two popular approaches to this problem would be to either use Parceable or some sort of serialization mechanism (such as GSON)

I hope those aren't the two most popular approaches, as they are probably the worst choices.

> How do I properly pass the information about the chapters that belong to the selected series to the new activity?

You don't. You pass an identifier of the series to the other activity, which then retrieves the relevant data and shows it.

If you were writing a Web app, and you wanted to link from a series to a page showing a list of episodes, you would not pass the entire list of episodes in some serialized fashion in the URL. Instead, you would supply some sort of identifier for the series. The Web app would then retrieve the list of episodes from wherever, based upon that identifier, and render the resulting Web page.

The same thing basically holds true in Android. You pass identifiers of what you want, enough so that the recipient can then go and retrieve the necessary data from the database, an in-memory POJO cache, the network, or wherever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fragment instead of an activity. You can then use an interface to access the data from the activity. Even better, just load the data within the fragment itself.